# Healthbar not decreasing when player is collided with the laser

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to decrease the healthbar of the player whenever he collides with an enemy laser but the script that I wrote is not working and it is giving me the following error:

> Assets/Scripts/Laser/HealthManager.cs(19,21): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type void' to UnityEngine.UI.Slider.

Can someone take some time and review my code and tell me why the healthbar is not working? Thank you.

HealthManager script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthManager : MonoBehaviour {
public int CurrentHealth { get; set; }
public int MaxHealth { get; set; }
public Slider HealthBar;
//public GameObject LaserBulletEnemyPreFab;
//public GameObject PlayerPrefab;
//public LaserLevelManager myLevelmanager;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    MaxHealth = 20;
    CurrentHealth = MaxHealth; //Resseting the health on start 
    HealthBar = CalculatingHealth();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(GetComponent<Collider>().gameObject.tag == "EnemyLaser")
    {
        Destroy(GetComponent<Collider>().gameObject);
        DealDamage(1);
    }
}

void DealDamage(int DamageValue)
{
    CurrentHealth -= DamageValue; //Deduct the damage dealt from the player's health
    HealthBar = CalculatingHealth();
    if(CurrentHealth <= 0) //If health is 0 
    {
        PlayerDead(); //Calling the function
    }
}

void CalculatingHealth()
{
    int healthdecrease =  CurrentHealth / MaxHealth;
}

void PlayerDead()
{
    CurrentHealth = 0; //Currenthealth is 0
    LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("Lose"); //Take player to the lose scene

   }


}
```

Comment: Are you sure DealDamage is ever called? I am not sure your if statement does what you want. Regardless of this CalculatingHealth() does not return the calculated value

Answer (score 3):

HealthBar is of type Slider. CalculatingHealth is a function that does not return anything (so void).
You try to set a variable initialy initialized to type Slider to a void value. This is not possible.

You could:

```
float CalculatingHealth()
{
    return healthdecrease =  CurrentHealth / MaxHealth;
}
```

And

```
HealthBar.value = CalculatingHealth();
```

Note: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Slider-value.html

Comment: But I can use integers if I want whole numbers, right?

Comment: @Mizzi Your health value can be a whole number but the value you feed `Slider.value` has to be a float between 0 and 1.  For example, if your character has 45/100 hp then you need to set `Slider.value` to 0.45f. That is what Andromelus's code will  do for you.

Comment: It is still not working :/ Once I press start the healthbar goes to 1hp and does not get decreased once it gets hit with the laser

Comment: @Mizzi at start currenHealth = 20, maxHealth = 20. 20/20 = 1

Comment: Makes sense on why it is giving me 1 lol thanks for shouting that out

Comment: @Mizzi if the problem is solved, consider tagging this answer as correct